# If arctan if uniformly continuous on $[-\infty,0]$ and $[0,+\infty]$ , how can I connect the both cases?

Tags: real-analysis

If $\arctan$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ , how can I connect the both cases, to get uniformly cont. on $\mathbb{R}$? Choosing  $\delta =\tan\epsilon$ does the job for both cases, but how can I connect them? If I choose $x$ from $(-\infty,0)$, and $y$ from $[0,\infty)$, what $\delta$ should I use?

Comment: I don’t quite understand your question. I imagine one of the $[$ or $]$ should be $(/)$. (Not to mention $\infty]$ and $[-\infty$ do not make sense)

Comment: Sorry my english is  not that good, but I got a delta  when I proved that if I choose $x$ and $y$ from $(-\infty, 0]$ , and another , when $x$ and $y$ is from $[0,\infty)$,(Which is the same, $\delta = tan\epsilon$ . But I didnt consider the case when example, $x$ is negative, and $y$ is positive, thats why I want to connect them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,0]$ as well as $[0,\infty)$. Let $\epsilon >0$. There exist $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2>0$ such that $|f (x)-f(y)| <\epsilon /2$ if $x,y \in (-\infty,0]$ and $|x-y| <\delta_1$, $|f (x)-f(y)| <\epsilon /2$ if $x,y \in (0,\infty]$ and $|x-y| <\delta_2$. Let $x,y$ be any real numbers with $|x-y| <\delta$ where $\delta$ is the minimum of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2>0$ . Clearly $|f (x)-f(y)| <\epsilon /2$ if $x$ and $y$ are both non-positive or both non-negative. Suppose $x <0<y$. Then $|x-0| <\delta_1$ so $|f(x)-f(0)| <\epsilon /2$. Also, $|y-0| <\delta_2$ so $|f(y)-f(0)| <\epsilon /2$. By triangle inequality we get $|f(x)-f(y) |< \epsilon /2+\epsilon /2=\epsilon $. The  case $y,0<x$ is similar.

Comment: Sorry, how did u use triangle theorem?

Comment: @Elekhey $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(0)|+|f(0)-f(y)|$. Note that $0$ is in both of the intervals $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that using Mean-Value Theorem we have, $$\frac{\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)}{x-y}=\frac{1}{1+c^2}<1$$ for some $c\in (x,y)$. So that, $|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|\leq |x-y|$. Hence, $\arctan:\Bbb R\to \big(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem: for $x,y \in \mathbb R$ there is $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that

$$\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)= \frac{1}{1+z^2}(x-y).$$

Hence

$$|\arctan(x)-|arctan(y)|\le |x-y|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Patchwork:

$\epsilon$ given.

0) $f$ is uniformly continuos on $[-1,1]$, compact Interval.

There is a $\delta_0$ s.t. $|x-y| <\delta_0$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon$, $x,y \in [-1,1]$.

Set $\delta_1:=\min (\delta_0, 1)$.

1)For  Interval $(-\infty,0] :$ There is a $\delta_2$

2)For Interval $[0,\infty):$ There  a $\delta_3$.

3)$\delta=\min(\delta_i)$, $i=1, 2, 3;$

Then $|x-y|<\delta$ implies  $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry. I misread your answer. I have deleted my comments.